# can not run the simple function program

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int sum();

//find the sum of two numbers entered by the user.


int main(){
    int n, m;
    printf("Enter two numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int result = sum(m, n);
    printf(result);
    getch();
    return 0;   
}




int sum(m, n){
    int c;
    c = m+n;
    return c;
}
```

i was just writing a simple program with function but i don't know why it is not running it tells me to debug can someone tell me what is the problem with it

Comment: Change `int sum()` and `int sum(m, n)` to be `int sum(int m, int n)`. Then change `printf(result);` to be `printf("%d", result);`

Comment: Ans what is the question? I think any up-to-date C compiler will emit a *lot* of warnings with that code, that should have helped you to find the issues *before* asking here. Didn't you get any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change int sum() ; to int sum(int, int) ;
Change printf(result) to printf("%d", result) ;
Change int sum(m, n) to int sum(int m, int n) ;(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z07cx.jpg)
Another way of writing above program is
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOXRY.jpg)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int sum(int n, int m);

//find the sum of two numbers entered by the user.


int main(){
    int n, m;
    printf("Enter two numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int result = sum(m, n);
    printf("%d",result);
    getch();
    return 0;   
}




int sum(int n, int m){
    int c;
    c = m+n;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged since they rarely explain what the problems are. And your code still has bugs that are likely to result in a crash.

Comment: now works test  submit to solve  problem :-)

Comment: it tested  there https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: Begging for reputation is strongly frowned upon here, and is likely to earn you only more downvotes and delete flags.  Also, you have still only corrected two of the numerous bugs in this program, and you still haven't offered a single word of explanation for the changes you did make.